# Primary display fails

Tags: release-hera, dual-boot, nvidia

After installing NVidia graphics, I am facing a strange issue. I had my external display connected when the drivers installed. And now my Primary display is gone.
When I disconnect the external display, nothing comes up on the primary display of my laptop.

However, when I have display2 connected, I can see the login screen and everything works.

What might I be doing wrong? I'm seeing something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8o4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings>display and try fixing your displays there. This may just be a nvidia driver issue or an issue with elementary OS. If the above does not work, open a bug in the elementary Github repository.